# Specify kotlin version in buildSrc kotlin convention plugin

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I am developing a Kotlin project with multiple subprojects as explained here
[Building Kotlin Applications with libraries Sample (gradle.org)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_building_kotlin_applications_multi_project.html)

Is it correct to specify the kotlin version as as shown below?
*file: buildSrc/build.gradle.kts*

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:<kotlin-version>")
}
```

Also, is it possible to move this kotlin version to a central location for declaring project-wide dependency version (for example gradle.properties or buildSrc/**/Dependencies.kt or versions catalog)? None of the approaches mentioned seems to be supported in buildSrc/build.gradle.kts.

Answer (score 4):

There are many approaches to specify the kotlin version (or versions of any dependency) at a centralized location in a Gradle Multimodule Project.

- [gradle.properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties)
- [buildSrc/**/Dependency.kt](https://proandroiddev.com/better-dependencies-management-using-buildsrc-kotlin-dsl-eda31cdb81bf)
- [versions catalog](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html#sub:central-declaration-of-dependencies)

However, if you are defining a [Kotlin Convention Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_building_kotlin_applications_multi_project.html) in **buildSrc**, the kotlin version is not available in **`buildSrc/build.gradle.kts`** using any of the methods mentioned above so as to pick the right **kotlin-gradle-plugin**.

For a workaround solution, use the following.

```
# file:<root>/gradle.properties

kotlinVersion=1.5.31
```

```kts
// file:<root>/buildSrc/build.gradle.kts

import java.io.*
import java.util.*

// read gradle.properties programmatically
val props = Properties()
FileInputStream(file("../gradle.properties")).use {
    props.load(it)
}

plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
    gradlePluginPortal()
}

dependencies {
    val kotlinVersion = props.getProperty("kotlinVersion")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${kotlinVersion}")
}
```

In all other `<root>/**/<subproject>/build.gradle.kts` files access the kotlinVersion like

```kts
val kotlinVersion = project.properties["kotlinVersion"]
```

In `settings.gradle.kts`, access the kotlinVersion like

```
val kotlinVersion:String by settings
```

If anyone from the Gradle team reading this, please provide an API to access gradle.properties consistently across any of the build script files.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by specifying `kotlinVersion` in `gradle.properties` file as below.

```
kotlinVersion=1.6.10
```

Keep `gradle.properties` file at outermost project level.

You can access `kotlinVersion` in any submodules and project as

```
//top level declaration
val kotlinVersion by extra(project.property("kotlinVersion"))
//usage in dependency block
"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlinVersion}"
```

To verify whether you are able to read it, you can specify following

```
println(project.property("kotlinVersion"))
```

This should print kotlin version as

```
> Configure project :
1.6.10
```

### build.gradle.kts file

```
val kotlinVersion by extra(project.property("kotlinVersion"))
println("${kotlinVersion}")

group = "com.company"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url = uri("https://repo.spring.io/milestone") }
    maven { url = uri("https://repo.spring.io/snapshot") }
    gradlePluginPortal()
}

dependencies {

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${kotlinVersion}")
}
```

---

### gradle.properties file

```
kotlin.code.style=official
#kotlin.parallel.tasks.in.project=true
#kapt.incremental.apt=true

org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.caching=false
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

kotlinVersion=1.6.10
```

---

Ref:

- [project_properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:project_properties)
- [extra_properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html#sec:extra_properties)

Comment: How do I access gradle.properties in buildSrc/build.gradle.kts? I tried `val kotlinVersion: String by project` and it doesn't work.

Comment: It appears gradle.properties is not available in `buildSrc/build.gradle.kts` even with the approach you mentioned.

Comment: you need to create that file in project. @KiranMohan

Comment: I meant *not accessible*. Also NOTE that I need to access the properties from **buildSrc**/build.gradle.kts specifically. From other <subprojects>/build.gradle.kts your approach works.

Answer (score 0):

in app gradle
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
and project gradle
ext.kotlin_version = "1.6.0"